# Trouble parsing XML with TBXML

Tags: ios, xml, tbxml

I'm having difficulties parsing this xml with TBXML in iOS :

`<ServiceResponse><Response>
    <Object type="java.lang.Integer">168</Object>
  </Response>
  <Exception/>
</ServiceResponse>`

I want to extract the "168" but I only achieve to extract the "java.lang.Integer"

Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't see the code right now but I've only tried the "[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"Object"]" ... I've the read the TBXML guide but it's not really helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBXML have `valueOfAttributeNamed` method which is used to get attribute values and `textForElement` method which is used to get element values.

So do like this.

```
if ([[TBXML elementName:objElement] isEqualToString:@"Object"])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[TBXML textForElement:objElement]) ;
}
```

instead of

```
[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"type" forElement:objElement]
```